# about the largest value an int can hold in c programming?

Tags: c

In my system, the size of int data type  is 4 bytes so the maximum value it can hold is 4294967296

here is the sample code

```
# include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
     int a = 4294967296;
     
     return 0;
}
```

even though the maximum value it can hold is 4294967296 still I am getting overflow warning. why?

the warning is, " overflow in implicit constant conversion"

thank you!!

Comment: Hint: is your `int` signed or unsigned?

Comment: it is signed one

Comment: @praveenpadala - what makes you think that the largest value an `int` can hold is 4294967296? And if, as you've said, you're using a signed `int`, then what is the smallest value a signed `int` can hold? Please edit your question and walk us through your logic for that. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful when developing portability code, there are still MCUs supporting 16-bit signed integer. If so, using the typedefs of <types.h> with `int32_t` or `uint32_t` as well as `int16_t` or `uint16_t` will help.

Comment: Note that `4294967296` is a 33-bit number.  Unclear why one would think this is a maximal `int`.

Comment: Rolled back this question, since OP edited the code in a way which changes the question.

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to remember such constants by heart or calculate them yourself. The largest `int` value is defined in the file `limits.h`. The file also defines the largest `short`, `unsigned int`, etc., as well as the smallest values for each integral data type:

```
#include <limits.h>
...
int a = INT_MAX;
short b = SHRT_MAX;
unsigned int c = UINT_MAX;
```

Answer (score 2):

`int` is a signed value, so it goes to negative too which effectively halves that amount in the positive realm. That warning is telling you that it will overflow into a negative number.

Comment: I forgot to mention it is signed one but it is not showing any warning up to the value 4294967295, even though it is signed int, why it is showing warning for only the value 4294967296 and above that value

Comment: @praveenpadala: If you are actually getting no warning for `int a = 4294967295;` but are getting a warning for `int a = 4294967296;`, that may be an interesting question. You should enter a question about that showing complete source code for each case and stating the full compiler name, version, and command-line switches.

Comment: @Eric: gcc only warns about `int a = 4294967295` if you specify `-Wconversion` or `-pedantic`. It warns about `int a = 4294967296` if you specify `-Woverflow`, which is included in `-Wall`. I'm not trying to justify or anything :-). Clang warns on both, at least in the versions I have installed.

Answer (score 1):

2,147,483,647 should be the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

*even though the maximum value it can hold is `4294967296` ?* **No**, it can't as `a` is default `signed` in your case. `INT_MAX` is `2147483647` not `4294967296`(it's `UINT_MAX + 1`)

So when you do

```
int a = 4294967296; /* it can hold max 2147483647 on 32-bit, more than this cause overflow */
```

it will overflow into a negative number(`INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`) & also the behavior on signed integer overflow is **undefined** by the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is absolutely correct by informing you about the overflow.

To make it a bit simpler imagine a 4 bit integer. A four bit integer can hold up to 2^4=16 different values. Each value can only be a combination of these four bits:

```
8 4 2 1
0 0 0 0 = 0*8 + 0*4 + 0*2 + 0*1 = 0
0 0 0 1 = 0*8 + 0*4 + 0*2 + 1*1 = 1
0 0 1 0 = 0*8 + 0*4 + 1*2 + 0*1 = 2
...
1 1 0 0 = 1*8 + 1*4 + 0*2 + 0*1 = 12
1 1 0 1 = 1*8 + 1*4 + 0*2 + 1*1 = 13
1 1 1 0 = 1*8 + 1*4 + 1*2 + 0*1 = 14
1 1 1 1 = 1*8 + 1*4 + 1*2 + 1*1 = 15
```

So therefore a four bit integer can have 16 different values but the largest value is 15 (= 16 - 1 = 2^4 - 1).

Back to a four byte integer which is made up of 32 bits. Same game as before: The 32 bits can be combined in 2^32 = 4294967296 different ways. The largest number that can be written by 32 bits is 2^32 - 1 = 4294967295.

To write a binary number of value 4294967296  you need an additional 33rd bit. Since your integer is only 32 bits long the compiler informs you about that.

Answer (score 0):

You calculated just correct! but you forgot to consider the fact that there can be negative numbers. For example suppose you have 5 numbers, 1 to 5 count as 5 numbers and so do -4 to 4. The number you mentioned (and as well as in the other answers) can be stored in an `unsigned int`, quite literally meaning "no sign", while a `signed int` can hold the same number of numbers but equally in the negative and positive directions totaling to the number you calculated so. If my answer does not help then [maybe this should.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science))

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled along this and want to clean up/clarify some things.

An int is signed, meaning even if it's 4 bytes, the max will be `2^31 - 1` (2,147,483,647)

OP, you changed the code part to be an unsigned int, which changes things.
In that case, the max will become `2^32 -1` (4,294,967,295).

In the first case, you were off by 2x because of the sign bit.
In the second case, you're still off by 1--**We need one bit for 0**!